# SoftLayer API How to get uplink port speed value from SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest and SoftLayer_Hardware

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For the provisioned SoftLayer virtual Server, and Bare metal servers.

Which attribute/method from  SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest and  SoftLayer_Hardware
can return the uplink port speed value of the device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the items in the billing item of the device and look for port speed value.

These RestFul will return the items

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/$HardwareID/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[children[item]]]

Method GET

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VSIID/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[children[item]]]

Method GET

Note: Replace $HardwareID and $VSIID with the ID of the hardware or VSI you wish to see the items
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To get items from a Virtual Guest/Hardware already provisioned, you can use the following GET requests:

```
* Virtual Guest:



   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vsi_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,description,order[id,items]]]]

* Hardware:

   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[hardware_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,description,order[id,items]]]]
```